# New to HTML/CSS and need with help moving the bottom list (one is on top of the other) up so its on the same level and to the right side of screen

Tags: html, css

I have two horizontal lists one has 3 items, the other has the social media logos is on the bottom of the 1st list on mobile. When I go past 768px, I want it no longer to be one over the other but the top list towards the left (not to the end of the container but left justified and the bottom socail media icon list same but to the right of the container. I have been trying everything I can think of in the media query but the socail media icons never move. What am I doing wrong?

I want it to look like this to this:
[img][https://i.imgur.com/qF1vk7X.png[/img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1NgN.png)

I am unable to get the media query right to do what I am trying to do. This is my code. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Church Website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Restoration Christian Church Ministries Church">
    <meta property="og:description" content="May God Bless You!">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:image" content="">
    <meta property="og:url" content="">
    <title>Restoration Christian Church Ministries Church - May God Bless You!</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Inter:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css">
    

</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="header-list">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column">
                        <ul class="header-list-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Salvation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <ul class="header-list-icons">
                        <li><a href="3"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="3"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="3"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="3"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
      AOS.init();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
:root {
    
    --color-primary: #6c5b7b;
    --color-secondary: #6c757d;
    --color-accent: #ff3400;
    --color-headings: #000;
    --color-headings-secondary:#fff;
    --color-text: #6c757d;
    --color-body: #918ca4;
    --color-footer-headings:#FFF;
    --color-footer-background: #6c5b7b;
    --color-background:#f8f9fa!important;
}

/* Define a rule using universal selector, grabbing all elements * as well as all elements after + beforeafter of before */
*,
*::after,
*::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Typography */
html {
    /* 62.5% of 16px = 10px */
    font-size: 62.5%;
}

.wrap {
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 80px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 80px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

body {
    font-family: 'DM Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: var(--color-text);
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    color: var(--color-headings);
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 4.5rem;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 4rem;
     }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 2.4rem;
    }
    
    h4 {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
}

/* Links */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link {
    color:#FFF
}

/* Header Block */
.header-block {
    background: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;    
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}


/* Lists */

  .header-list {
    background: #6c5b7b;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  .header-list a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header-list a:hover {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  
  .header-list .header-list-list, .header-list .header-list-list li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .header-list .header-list-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  
  .header-list .header-list-icons, .header-list .header-list-icons li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .header-list .header-list-icons li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .header-list .header-list-icons li a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .header-list .header-list-icons li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 0px;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .header-list .header-list-icons li:first-child a {
      padding-left: 0px;
      
    }
    
  }
```

I tried using inline block, changing the structure of the classes, tried using float in the media query and starting from scratch but nothing seems to work. I am able to change font size or color in the media query so it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make row css

```
row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

and on screen less 768 or less, make

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Well, that partially worked! Looks perfect on larger screens but on mobile, it gets a bit off. The Home and About Us are on one line, Salvation is below Home and the last social media icon is under the Facebook icon.

Comment: @Crazz2323 Your next step is probably to use media queries to change how it appears on different screen size ranges. "Breakpoints" is a keyword that will help there when searching. Best practice is to design it for mobile (I use 375px width) and then scale it up from there.

Comment: Thanks! Actually was using media queries and was stumped on why I couldn't get the query to change what I was looking to change in my original post. Still learning so what's probably simple for some is a time sink for me. I really appreciate everyone's assistance! Never would have thought of adding the edits to the row and putting the query suggested. I was trying to do the query on the list items. Spent a whole day trying to figure it out. I'm very close to getting it right and I know enough to know it's probably an easy fix, any guidance is definitely appreciated! Will keep looking.

Comment: Welcome! Upvote if this answer is useful.